# Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found

Tags: qt, qt5, shared-libraries, conda

This question is asked several times in Stack Overflow. I tried methods in several discussions but it didn't work. So my `OpenCV` library which was built with custom `Qt` doesn't work properly:

```py
import cv2
img = cv2.imread("IMAGE_PATH")
cv2.imshow("frame", img)

qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, xcb.

Aborted (core dumped)
```

### What I have tried

- I tried setting `export QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1` and execute a Python script having OpenCV plotting an image. Error message:

```sh
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/w/.conda/envs/py36/plugins/platforms" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/w/.conda/envs/py36/plugins/platforms/libqeglfs.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/w/.conda/envs/py36/plugins/platforms/libqeglfs.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "eglfs"
        ]
    },
    "className": "QEglFSIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 329991
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("eglfs")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/w/.conda/envs/py36/plugins/platforms/libqminimal.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/w/.conda/envs/py36/plugins/platforms/libqminimal.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "minimal"
        ]
    },
    "className": "QMinimalIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 329991
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("minimal")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/w/.conda/envs/py36/plugins/platforms/libqminimalegl.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/w/.conda/envs/py36/plugins/platforms/libqminimalegl.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "minimalegl"
        ]
    },
    "className": "QMinimalEglIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 329991
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("minimalegl")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/w/.conda/envs/py36/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/w/.conda/envs/py36/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "offscreen"
        ]
    },
    "className": "QOffscreenIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 329991
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("offscreen")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/w/.conda/envs/py36/plugins/platforms/libqvnc.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/w/.conda/envs/py36/plugins/platforms/libqvnc.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "vnc"
        ]
    },
    "className": "QVncIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 329991
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("vnc")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/w/.conda/envs/py36/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/w/.conda/envs/py36/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "xcb"
        ]
    },
    "className": "QXcbIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 329991
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("xcb")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/w/.conda/envs/py36/bin/platforms" ...
Cannot load library /home/w/.conda/envs/py36/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so: (/home/w/.conda/envs/py36/plugins/platforms/../../lib/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5: symbol _ZN11QFontEngine14bitmapForGlyphEj6QFixedRK10QTransform, version Qt_5_PRIVATE_API not defined in file libQt5Gui.so.5 with link time reference)
QLibraryPrivate::loadPlugin failed on "/home/w/.conda/envs/py36/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so" : "Cannot load library /home/w/.conda/envs/py36/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so: (/home/w/.conda/envs/py36/plugins/platforms/../../lib/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5: symbol _ZN11QFontEngine14bitmapForGlyphEj6QFixedRK10QTransform, version Qt_5_PRIVATE_API not defined in file libQt5Gui.so.5 with link time reference)"
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, xcb.

Aborted (core dumped)
```

- I tried setting `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/Qt5.14.0/5.14.0/gcc_64/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in `~/.bashrc` file but it didn't solve.
- I tried reinstalling `Qt5` but it didn't work.
- I tried using `ldd` as people said but I am not so sure what information I should be looking.

### If relevant

- First, if relevant, I have Anaconda installed on Ubuntu 16.04 and I created a general Python environment name `py36` where several libraries are installed. I tried running `conda list` and the following are some of the packages:

```sh
 ...
 pyqt                      5.9.2            py36h05f1152_2  
 qt                        5.9.7                h5867ecd_1
 vtk                       8.2.0           py36haa4764d_200
 ...
```

I honestly didn't know when these libraries are installed (They came installed automatically when I installed other packages.)

- Next, I downloaded [Qt offline installer](https://www.qt.io/offline-installers) and installed to `/opt/Qt-5.14.0`.
- Next, I compiled OpenCV 3.4.9 using the following settings. I went well without any errors. (After that I set symlink `cv2.so` in the conda environment to point to the built OpenCV library in `/opt`.)

```sh
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
-D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/OpenCV/opencv-3.4.9 \
-D CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="/opt/Qt5.14.0/5.14.0/gcc_64/lib/cmake;/opt/vtk-8.2.0/lib/cmake;/opt/g2o/lib/cmake" \
-D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/home/w/OpenCV/opencv-3.4.9/opencv_contrib-3.4.9/modules \
-D PYTHON3_EXECUTABLE=/home/w/.conda/envs/py36/bin/python3 \
-D WITH_OPENGL=ON \
-D WITH_V4L=ON \
-D WITH_LIBV4L=ON \
-D WITH_FFMPEG=ON \
-D WITH_VTK=ON \
-D WITH_QT=ON \
-D WITH_GTK=ON \
..
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error seems to be the `Qt` library conflict. The linker couldn't find the correct `Qt` library (installed in `/opt` folder) which is required by my custom built `OpenCV` in the conda virtual environment. This is because there is another `Qt` library installed in the virtual environment. And this can be found by using `ldd`. (Sorry, it was some time ago so I don't have the output.)

As expected, by removing all the Qt-related libraries in the virtual conda environment, the `OpenCV` library which was built with `Qt` (installed in `/opt` folder) works properly as usual.

Comment: How did you find and remove the libraries?

Answer (score 19):

It is likely caused by a missing library, although not necessarily one listed in the other answers. Here is how you can figure it out for yourself.

Set the environment variable `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1` and then run your application. This should give more detailed information on why it failed. For example when I ran it with my app, I saw:

```
qt.core.plugin.loader: QLibraryPrivate::loadPlugin failed on "/home/david/work/junk/pywebview-test/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so" : "Cannot load library /home/david/work/junk/pywebview-test/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so: (libxcb-cursor.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)"
```

This means a library linked to the one listed is probably missing. To find out which one exactly, run the following replacing the full path based on your error message:

```
ldd /home/david/work/junk/pywebview-test/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so
```

On my computer, this showed a line with:

```
libxcb-cursor.so.0 => not found
```

So I installed the missing library with:

```
sudo apt install libxcb-cursor0
```

Once all missing libraries are installed, try running the app again.

Answer (score 6):

I'm on ubuntu linux.
I made sure to remove any pyqt5 related packages, and checked their existence using pip freeze (`pip freeze | grep -i qt`).

I'm not sure how it resolved the problem, but I assume that there is some inner-conflict with pip loading the packages.

to resolve the removed pyqt packages, I used `sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5` instead.
this works because pip tries to load cv2 & pyqt from `python3/site-packages` directory, where packages from apt-get are loaded from `python3/dist-packages`, and thus the conflict is resolved.

I deduced it from looking into why it worked with apt-get (dist-packages), and from looking at `sys.path` inside the python interpreter. in my case `site-packages` proceeded `dist-packages`

Answer (score 2):

For me this resolved the issue:

```sh
sudo apt-get install libxcb-xinerama0
```

Reference: https://forum.qt.io/post/616242

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on Debian 10 trying to run spyder. Fixed the issue installing the .deb file from here:

https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/amd64/libxcb-util1/download

Answer (score 0):

Even though I have no idea *why* this works, after trying everything else on the internet, simply *deleting* the libqxcb.so file from the pyqt plugins solved the issue for me. If anyone knows why this fixed the issue for me (while reinstalling things did not), please let me know.

The way to do this is to go to the folder mentioned in the error message, go to the `platforms` subfolder, and then delete the `libqxcb.so` file in there. For me, the message was `Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "/home/MyUsername/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cv2/qt/plugins" even though it was found.`, so I deleted `/home/MyUsername/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cv2/qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so`. If you, like me, can't find any other solutions to this issue, you could try this. Or, to be more safe, move it to some backup location so that you could place it back if something else breaks more catastrophically.